# Django: typehinting backward / related_name / ForeignKey relationships

Tags: python, django, type-hinting, django-stubs

Let's say we have the following models:

```
class Site(models.Model):
    # This is djangos build-in Site Model
    pass

class Organization(models.Model):
    site = models.OneToOneField(Site)
```

And if I use this somewhere in some other class:

```
organization = self.site.organization
```

Then mypy complains:

```
Site has no attribute "organization"
```

How can I make mypy happy here?

Answer (score 12):

Django adds backwards relations at runtime which aren't caught by `mypy` which only does static analysis.

To make `mypy` happy (and to make it work with your editor's autocomplete) you need to add an explicit type hint to `Site`:

```py
class Site(models.Model):
    organization: "Organization"

class Organization(models.Model):
    site = models.OneToOneField(Site)
```

Using quotes around the type is needed since we are doing a [forward reference](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#forward-references) to `Organization` before it has been defined.

For foreign keys and many-to-many relationships, you can do the same thing, but using a `QuerySet` type hint instead:

```py
class Organization(models.Model):
    site = models.OneToOneField(Site)
    employees: models.QuerySet["Employee"]

class Employee(models.Model):
    organization = models.ForeignKey(
        Organization,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="employees",
    )
```

---

EDIT: There is a [django-stubs](https://pypi.org/project/django-stubs/) package which is meant to integrate with `mypy`, however I haven't used it personally. It may provide a solution for this without having to explicitly add type hints to models.

Answer (score -5):

I just know a litle of english, and i don't know this is true. But you can add

> site = models.OneToOneField(Site, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

Comment: and you can add related_name in relationship of site